# Office-ui-fabric-core some icons are not showing

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, ms-project, office-ui-fabric

I am building office addins for Project. It is really weird that even though I am using proper icon names some icons are not showing

Followed everything from the official documentation

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/get-started#fabric-core

and the CSS CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/10.0.0/css/fabric.min.css" />
```

In Project Taskpane: Side loading State

[image]

Using the correct format **in HTML:**

> ```
>    <li class="ms-ListItem">
>     <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--MapLayers"></i>
>     <span class="ms-font-m ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary">Export *****"
> ```

Note: Here MapLayers is the icon which is failed to load.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed that the [CSS](https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/10.0.0/css/fabric.min.css) you're importing doesn't actually have the "--MapLayers" class.
Though some of the Office UI documentation (like this one: https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/) shows MapLayers exists as an icon in the "FabricMDL2Icons" font family, I don't think it does, or at least not in whatever version of the font family this other documentation uses: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/web/icons (you can search by MapLayers and notice that it won't be found on this 2nd site). You'll also notice that the "MayLayers" icon is '\uE81E', but I think that's only in the "Segoe MDL2 Assets" font-family (which is native to Windows 10: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font).

If you open Windows 10's character map, change the font family, and navigate to U+E81E, you'll find it!

[image: MapLayers unicode character in Segoe MDL2 Assets]

Basically, if you want to use the MapLayers icon, you'll need to make your own CSS MapLayers class that uses "Segoe MDL2 Assets" as the font-family and has content of "\E81E". Here is a hacky demo where I overloaded the AADLogo class in the codepen to make it show the MapLayers icon:
[image: MapLayers icon with custom CSS]

However, I think this would only work on Windows 10 PCs (unless your website includes the Segoe MDL2 Assets font-family as a resource?). Perhaps someone from the Office UI team can comment on the discrepancies between the various documentations or if MapLayers is coming soon with a font-family version upgrade or something...

But if you're just interested in getting a MapLayers icon to show up, I think you'd need to do the following:
1. Making your own CSS class for it with "Segoe MDL2 Assets" as the font-family
2. Use "\E81E" as the CSS content
2b. Directly include the "Segoe MDL2 Assets" font-family in your site (which may or may not be against Microsoft's terms of service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/font-faq#document-embedding).

Comment: Excellent this is really clear instructions. Thank you !!

Answer (score 4):

I have tried few more available icons from the link

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/web/icons

Example: BackgroundColor

[image]

Surprisingly some are loading some are not loading again.

Then I added the following class for my parent div. Then the icons were displaying.

```
<body class="ms-Fabric" dir="ltr">
  <span class="ms-font-su ms-fontColor-BackgroundColor">Big blue text</span>
</body>
```

Here class is "ms-Fabric"

**Note: I am loading fabric core from cdn via index.html.**

May be this will help some one facing same problem..

Comment: Well the link is from the Office UI Fabric *React* library's Icon class component which inherently puts the required nesting of classes for their icon set. The one you were using is the Fabric Core (vanilla js) library. I think the React lib's icon set is a superset (or same set) of whatever the Core library is showing you on their documentation page since the React library (requires/)uses the same CSS stylesheet. But yea, my old Office Ui React app required putting "ms-Fabric" class on the root app I think.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I wish the documentation should be more clear than confusing

Comment: actually dir="ltr" was my problem - only a few icons were missing - as soon as I added dir="ltr" the missing icons came back